# docker-compose got error when bringing up nodejs application docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and I am trying to use docker-compose to start node application container and I keep getting error when it starts node application and I don't understand how the path at current context work when docker-compose bring up container. 
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:4.7
MAINTAINER anna

RUN mkdir -p /bbb/abc
ADD build /bbb/abc/
ADD package.json /bbb/abc/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/abc
RUN cd /bbb/abc/ && \
  npm install --production && \
  rm package.json


EXPOSE 3080
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /bbb/abc/server/
CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

and here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  abc:
    image: bbb-abc-n
    container_name: abc
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /bbb/abc/server/
    ports:
      - "3080:3080"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - NODE_PATH=/bbb/abc/server/
      - WORKDIR=/bbb/abc/server/
    volumes:
      - /var/log/abc:/var/log/bis/bcs
```

then I do a build

```
> docker build -t bbb-abc-n
```

Then if I run docker run then container is up and node application is started correctly as

```
> docker run -p 3080:3080 --name abc -d bbb-abc-n
```

This worked good as I expected.

However, if I run with using docker-compose to start container as follow:

```
> docker-compose up
```

And I got the error below and I don't understand how the path context with docker-compose and how to debug this.

This is error I got:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../appconfig/production.json'
abc    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
abc    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
abc    |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
abc    |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
abc    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/bis/bcs/server/utils/logger.js:6:17)
abc    |     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
abc    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
abc    |     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
abc    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
abc    |     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
abc    |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Thanks for any help

Anna

Comment: Just a guess, according to this `/bis/bcs/server/utils/logger.js` you tried to load logger configuration. Probably you define path to it as `../blah/blah` try to change it to `__dirname + /../blah/blah` or use `path.resolve`

Comment: thanks Nazar.  However, it's still not working for me.